# Wireless Connectivity Issue: "This device is using an alternative driver"

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

Even after selecting "Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)," my wireless networks are still not showing for me to connect.
Under the heading "Broadcom Corporation: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter" it reads, "This device is using an alternative driver."

This is my first day with Ubuntu, so I do not know the terminal; anything I can do to get my wireless driver in working order?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: same problem here